# jQuery localScroll - Not working with links that have unusual punctuation/characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto

We're using the great plugin called localScroll with scrollTo on our university wiki and it's made this scrolling task very easy, it works great. The wiki has an automated table of contents for longer pages that links to any h1 to h4 header.

There is one issue I've not been able to resolve:

When the headers on our wiki include parenthesis, exclamation mark or question marks, etc., the smooth scrolling effect does not work. (The headers & #links have automated anchors tags on them in the wiki that match the header text). It's configured simply as follows:

```
    $('.content-wrapper').localScroll ({
    duration:900,         
    });
```

/marco

Comment: post some examples of the linsk including href and corresponding anchor id

Comment: @charlietfl - This is a link from a list that is generated by the table of contents macro on the wiki:
<a class="toc-link" href="#(ChapterOne)">Chapter One</a> and the anchors tags on the headers are as follows: <h2>
<a name="(ChapterOne)"></a>
Chapter One
</h2>

Answer (score 0):

You might well be able to parse the href and corresponding anchor id to remove special characters from both prior to initializing scroll plugin. Without seeing an actual page and protocol for href used following is the concept:

```
var $links=$('.someClass a');

$links.each(function(){
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    /* find corresponding anchor */
    var matchAnchor= $('[id="'+href+'"]');
    /* remove all special chars */
    href=href.replace(/\W/g,'');
    /* replace link href*/
    $(this).attr('href', '#'+href);

    /* replace anchor id*/
    matchAnchor.attr('id', href);   

});
```

Comment: As follow-up, I've not had success with this yet, but am working on the problem and will post results once the champagne is corked.